# Javascript: What counts as "User interacting with webpage?"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that plays an audio file when a value on the page changes to alert the user that it has changed. Sometimes it works, but other times it says that the "play()" method was not allowed because "The user has not interacted with the webpage."

It will usually work when the webpage is first loaded, but when navigated away within the same site it will often throw this error.

This question can be split into two smaller questions:

1. What counts as a "User interaction," in Chrome? I can't seem to find any information on this.
2. Is there any way to check using Javascript if the "User interaction," flag has been set?

Comment: User interactions are things like clicking or scrolling in the web page. It's possible to trigger these events programmatically, but the browser will block certain things when they are not triggered specifically by the user to protect the user from malicious code.

Comment: If it's a Chrome security feature it may be intended that you cannot do anything until the user has truly interacted with the page, and it may be necessary to accept that. What code have you tried so far to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the Web Audio API. From the [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Best_practices#Autoplay_policy):

> Browsers have started to implement an autoplay policy, which in
> general can be summed up as:
>
> > "Create or resume context from inside a user gesture".

This is to prevent webpages from blaring audio on page load without interaction from the user. The docs go on to state:

> But what does that mean in practice? A user gesture has been
> interpreted to mean a user-initiated event, normally a `click` event.
> Browser vendors decided that Web Audio contexts should not be allowed
> to automatically play audio; they should instead be started by a user.
> This is because autoplaying audio can be really annoying and
> obtrusive. But how do we handle this?
>
> When you create an audio context (either offline or online) it is
> created with a `state`, which can be `suspended`, `running`, or `closed`.
>
> When working with an `AudioContext`, if you create the audio context
> from inside a `click` event the `state` should automatically be set to
> `running`.

Source: [Web Audio API best practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Best_practices#Autoplay_policy)

Comment: So since this is a chrome extension, would appending a useless button to the page called "Activate," satisfy the user interaction, or would it be better to have that button start an async loop that plays the audio when a variable changes? IE: `While (pageValue < 0){do nothing}; audio.play();`

Comment: My understanding is that the button is just needed to start the audio context. Once it's started you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Can I start the audio context without playing the audio right away?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: Ok... how? I'm not really sure what the "audio context," is your referring to. Is it just the `let myAudio = new Audio('file');`?

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure when it comes to playing audio from a file. I've only generated audio, for which there's a specific context that has to be initiated.

Comment: For whatever reason it would seem a `tap` from a mobile phone does not count as user interaction. Where for example opening a confirm dialog on the desktop counts, the exact same setup on a phone will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.

The extension now appends a button to the top of the page called "Activate." When it's clicked, it calls:

```
function checkVal(){
    if ( /*check if the value has changed*/ ){
        let myAudio = new Audio('my_audio.mp3');
        myAudio.play();
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(checkVal, 5);
    }
}
```

It's a little hacky, but it works for my purposes.